# Why does my Laravel project have 2 different Cart object with different ID?

Tags: php, laravel, object, shopping-cart

Like the title, i don't know why i have 2 Cart objects with different IDs in my project. Could you guys give me any ideas about this problem? And how to fix it? Many thanks!

I use the same way to get Session, but they create 2 different objects
Here i have my getCheckOut() function

```
public function getCheckOut(Request $request){

        if(Auth::check()){
            if ($request->has('change_info')) {
                if($request->change_info == 'billing'){
                    $payer = $request->payer_name;
                    $payer_phone = $request->payer_phone;
                    $billing_address = $request->billing_address;
                    Session::put('checkout_info.payer',$payer);
                    Session::put('checkout_info.payer_phone',$payer_phone);
                    Session::put('checkout_info.billing_address',$billing_address);

                }elseif ($request->change_info == 'shipping') {
                    $receiver = $request->receiver_name;
                    $receiver_phone = $request->receiver_phone;
                    $shipping_address = $request->shipping_address;
                    Session::put('checkout_info.receiver',$receiver);
                    Session::put('checkout_info.receiver_phone',$receiver_phone);
                    Session::put('checkout_info.shipping_address',$shipping_address);
                }
            }

            $oldCart  = Session::get('cart');
            $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
            dd($cart);
            $checkout_info = Session::get('checkout_info');
            return view('customer.checkout',['cart' => $cart, 'items' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice, 'checkout_info' => $checkout_info]);
        }else{
            Session::put('to_checkout',1);
            return redirect('login')->with('loi','Please login your account');
        }
    }
```

and my applyPromoCode() function

```
public function applyPromoCode(Request $request){

        $oldCart  = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $codes = PromoCode::where('name',$request->promo_code)->get();

        if(count($codes) > 0){
            $code = $codes[0];
            if($code->fixed != 0){
                $amount = $code->fixed;
                if($cart->totalPrice > $amount){
                    $totalAfterDiscount = $cart->totalPrice - $amount;
                }elseif ($cart->totalPrice <= $amount) {
                    $totalAfterDiscount = 0;
                }
            }elseif ($code->percentage != 0) {
                $amount = $cart->totalPrice * $code->percentage / 100;
                $totalAfterDiscount = $cart->totalPrice - $amount;
            }
            $cart->discountAmount = $amount;
            $cart->totalAfterDiscount = $totalAfterDiscount;
            $cart->promoCode = 1;
            Session::put('cart',$cart);
            Session::save();

            // $checkout_info = Session::get('checkout_info');
            // $newCart = Session::get('cart');
            // $cart = new Cart($newCart);
            // dd($cart->promoCode);
            return redirect('checkout');
            // return view('customer.checkout',['cart' => $cart, 'items' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice, 'checkout_info' => $checkout_info]);
        }else{
            return redirect('checkout')->with('loi','Your code is invalid');
        }
```

i use dd() to check and got 2 different carts

**getCheckOut() gets this cart:**

[cart#423](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u1pW.jpg)

**and applyPromoCode() gets this cart**

[cart#411](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mZJb.jpg)

after promo code is applied

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOsI0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

what is the different between 2 objects?

Comment: they have same attributes but different data. The promo code is applied to cart#411 not cart#423